# How to filter queryset for all subcategories

Tags: django

I have a model:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=127)
    # Lookups would be as follows:
    # cat = Category.objects.get(...)
    # for sub_cat in cat.sub_categories.all():
    parent = models.ForeignKey(
        "self",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="sub_categories")
```

Obviously in templates I can filter for all the subcategories:

```
{% for sub_cat in cat.sub_categories.all %}
```

I would like to pass the queryset of subcategories to the form:

```
self.fields['parent'].queryset = PoliciesAndProceduresCategory.subcategories.all()
```

But this gives the error:

> AttributeError: type object 'PoliciesAndProceduresCategory' has no attribute 'subcategories'

Is there an easy way to filter for this here or do I have to do something such as defining a `Model Method`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found out how:

```
self.fields['parent'].queryset = Category.objects.filter(parent=None)
```

problem was I tried:

```
self.fields['parent'].queryset = Category.objects.filter(parent=False)
```

I was getting my JS and Django mixed up!